# how do you required a user to login using key authentication?

Tags: ssh, login, authentication

I have created a new user and have generated them an *rsa* key on my local machine and manage to copy the public key content into that user `ssh/authorized_key` dir in the server.

But somehow that user is able to log in without requiring a key. ie `ssh newuser@localhost`. tThey can also log in using `ssh -i "keyname" newuser@localhost`.

Comment: Just because they're not specifying the keyfile explicitly (with the `-i` option) doesn't mean they are not logging in using the key

Comment: can you elaborate more on this. I'm new to linux and one part of a project requirement that i have to do is to make sure Key-based SSH authentication is enforced. the grader was able to log in with the newuser account i set up without using a key or password.

Answer (score 0):

!!!! ONLY DO THIS IF YOU REALLY REALLY WANT TO DISABLE PASSWORD LOGIN FOR SSH DAEMON !!!!

to get this working you must tell the ssh daemon that you do not want passwords, this should be done ONLY if we know key login is possible at all:

you must edit this file:

```
/etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

and change the following values:

original:

```
RSAAuthentification yes
```

should be:

```
RSAAuthentification no
```

original:

```
#AuthorizedKeysFile %h/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

should be:

```
AuthorizedKeysFile %h/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

original:

```
#IgnoreUserKnowHosts yes
ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

should be:

```
IgnoreUserKnowHosts yes
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
PasswordAuthentication no
```

finally restart the sshd daemon:

```
/etc/init.d/ssh restart
```

Comment: made the changes to the config and restarted. now i can't log in at all with any user even with the key. keep getting connection refused

Comment: then we know that the setting is correct but something is wrong with your key settings.  What is the access level of your private key? it should be 0600.

Comment: i am not sure. i'm using amazon lightsail for my instance and is the default private key that i download used before, but it won't work now. also the key gen rsa n pub for the new user won't work either. is there anyway i can get back into the instance?

Comment: do an `ll Location/of/your/private/key` on your private key and check the access level. I do not know AWS but for all Server I used, I have a Webfrontend where I can connect to my servers. So how do you try to connect to your instance?

Comment: how do i do that? amazon has a browser based connection but after you mod the config file it no longer works. only way ive been able to connect with through a terminal using the key i downloaded but that no longer works

Comment: key #1 return -rw-r--r-- 1 Name 197121 1704
key #2 return -rw-r--r-- 1 Name 197121 1679

Comment: normaly that should work but please change it to 0600 instead of 0644.

Comment: If this still dont work you should reset your instance to gain access again. I could only help if I would own the settings for the instance and if I would get the private key, but that is always a bad idea. And next time do not disable password login if you cannot login with keys.

Comment: can't reset amazon lightsail instance, only reboot. I tried lgging in with the keys i have before and it doesn't work. I wouldn't have made the changes if i had known that none of the keys won't work anymore.

Comment: AFAIK the property name is `PasswordAuthentication` **not** `PasswordAuthentification`

Comment: So I'm new to this area here, but right now I learned, that before telling anybody anything you must verify, that all basics are clear. Means who would have the idea to disable password logins if no other login is working!!!!! So if you were not able to login to whatever you have, ask somebody who knows how to do that.

Comment: thanks steeldriver I update the PasswordAuthentication  section